# issue Starting AVD on Arch linux

Tags: android, linux, android-virtual-device

I have installed the android sdk and sdk tools. I have setup ANDROID_HOME variable. I have also created a virtual device. Within the command line when entering "emulator @avd-name" I receive an error. That error is "emulator:cd: no such file or directory: emulator () {\n\tcd "$(dirname "$(which emulator)")" && ."

What am I doing incorrectly

Comment: The Emulator location has recently moved. Are you using at least: Android SDK Tools v26.01, Android Emulator v26.1.0, & Android Platform tools v26.0.0? Also, how did you create your Android Virtual Device?

Comment: I created the AVD using the android SDK

Comment: I recommend that you create the AVD via the AVD Manager found in the last version of Android Studio. In the AVD Manager we add parameters and setup settings that are not available in the stand alone & deprecated SDK Manager.